Induced G-modules are a direct sum
In the book Class field theory by J. Milne he defines an induced $G$-module to be of the form $\operatorname{Hom}_{\textsf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}[G],A)=\operatorname{Hom}_{\textsf{Set}}(G,A)$ for some abelian group $A$, the action given by $(g'\cdot f)(g)=f(gg')$. Then, in a remark, he says that a $G$-module $M$ is induced if and only if it is of the form $$M=\bigoplus_{g\in G}gM_0$$ for some subgroup $M_0\subset M$.
My question is, how to prove this? Moreover, what is the action of $G$ on this direct sum? If $M$ is induced it is equal to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\textsf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}[G],A)$ for some abelian group $A$. In this case, $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\textsf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z}[G],A)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\textsf{Ab}}\left(\bigoplus_{g\in G}\mathbb{Z},A\right)\cong \bigoplus_{g\in G}\operatorname{Hom}_{\textsf{Ab}}(\mathbb{Z},A)\cong\bigoplus_{g\in G}A.$$ But the $g$'s are missing on the right hand side. Also, what is the action? Is it just, permutating the coordinates? i.e, if $a$ is in the coordinate $gg'$ then $g'$ acts moving $a$ to the coordinate $g$ (so it is a shift to the left). My guess is that this is true. The $gA$ doesn't mean nothing specific in this context, and the action on the direct sum is just permutation. With this in mind, to a homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{Z}[G]\to A$ we assign the tuple $(f(g))_{g\in G}\in \bigoplus_{g\in G}A$. Denote this assignment by $\theta$. Then \begin{align*}\theta(g'\cdot f)&=((g'\cdot f)(g))_{g\in G}\\
&=(f(gg'))_{g\in G}\\
&=g'\cdot(f(g))_{g\in G}.\end{align*}
This seems artificial to me. Any help?
